# Batch File Loops

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a small batch file to automate some networking troubleshooting commands we use on a daily basis.

I have created a simple menu, but when I try to run a loop command it errors out and won't complete the loop.  Option 1 (SURVEY) runs fine, but the PINGER section just kills the command prompt without doing anything.

```
SET /P M=Type 1, 2, 3, or 4 then press ENTER:
IF %M%==1 GOTO SURVEY
IF %M%==2 GOTO PINGER
IF %M%==3 GOTO MAP
IF %M%==4 GOTO EOF

:SURVEY
echo 3 Point WiFi Survey... Please Wait...
echo ===================================================================================================== >> surveyresults.txt
echo 3 Point WiFi Survey Results >> surveyresults.txt
netsh wlan show networks bssid >> surveyresults.txt
echo 3 Point WiFi Survey Complete
echo ===================================================================================================== >> surveyresults.txt 
GOTO MENU

:PINGER
echo Pinging Devices on Subnet... Please Wait...
echo ===================================================================================================== >> surveyresults.txt 
echo Device Pings >> surveyresults.txt
FOR /L %i IN (1,1,254) DO ping -a -n 1 192.168.1.%i | FIND /i "Reply" >> surveyresults.txt
echo Pinging Complete
echo ===================================================================================================== >> surveyresults.txt 
GOTO MENU

:EOF
```

Comment: Batch files require the `%` character of for loop metavariables to be escaped by doubling them. `%%i`

Comment: Not quite sure what you talking about there - I have literally just seen the answer to my question.  The following day - not 2 hours ago as you suggest.

Comment: I checked your last seen time in your profile Colin, which is at the time of this posting 34 minutes ago, i.e 2021-04-13 @ 12:12:54Z. Based upon your comment above, being 2021-04-13 @ 12:14:35Z, that shows the accuracy of the data. There is no valid reason to have visited a site where you have only one live question, and where you will clearly see notification that your question has been answered, and not check out that answer. I am satisfied with the data indicating that you had indeed seen my answer, and provided no feedback within two hours of doing so. Thank you for marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main issues with your script.

1. You are using the wrong command `SET /P` for user input of a known list of menu entries. You should be using the `CHOICE` utility. *Open a Command Prompt window type `choice /?` and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key to see its usage information.*
2. You have not read the help information for the `FOR` command, *`for /?`*, which specifically states `To use the FOR command in a batch program, specify %%variable instead of %variable`.

Here therefore is an improved rewrite of **everything** you included in your submitted [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C 1234
If ErrorLevel 4 GoTo :EOF
If ErrorLevel 3 GoTo MAP
If ErrorLevel 2 GoTo PINGER

:SURVEY
(   Echo 3 Point WiFi Survey... Please Wait... > CON
    Echo =====================================================================================================
    Echo 3 Point WiFi Survey Results
    %SystemRoot%\System32\netsh.exe WLAN Show Networks BSSID
    Echo 3 Point WiFi Survey Complete > CON
    Echo =====================================================================================================
) >> "surveyresults.txt" 
GoTo MENU

:PINGER
(   Echo Pinging Devices on Subnet... Please Wait... > CON
    Echo =====================================================================================================
    Echo Device Pings
    For /L %%G In (1,1,254) Do %SystemRoot%\System32\PING.EXE -a -n 1 192.168.1.%%G | %SystemRoot%\System32\find.exe /i "Reply"
    Echo Pinging Complete > CON
    Echo =====================================================================================================
) >> "surveyresults.txt" 
GoTo MENU
```